# How do I write/translate a square root Method in c#?

Tags: c#

I just want to let you know: this is a repeat of a question Ive already asked, but was closed down. I really want an answer to this but I dont have the patience to wait until they reopen the question since its already been closed for quite some time.

I'm supposed to write a calculator in C# and I've done most of the things, but I'm not sure how to write a root method.

I've looked around, but I'm just not able to translate some of the things online into proper C# code.

Since this was closed due to inaccuracy: I cant use `Sqrt` since I'm supposed to do it myself. I've already written things for all the other operators and now I want to be able to do a a^(b/c) which is just root^c(a^b). I've done all the separation and now I have

```
public double RootMethod(double rootExponent, double number)
{

    double result = 1;
     //calculate result
    return result;
}
```

Whilst I do have my own actual number classes with operator methods, I only want a "normal" example" since I think I'll be able to translate to my operators. So you can even use some Math methods (as long as it's not `Sqrt`) because I translated most of those. If you use one I can't use, I'll tell you, but for now I just really want to see *some* example in C#.

Also Important YES you CAN use Math.Pow in your suggestion, NO I cant use it myself, since this is what I need to write myself BUT Ive already written the POW base translation to work for my classes so I should just be able to swap that method out.

Ive looked around multiple Foroums and I know that there are way to calculate Roots without using one, but Im not able to really understand the ways Ive found, yet alone translate them to c# code.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Math.Log()` etc?

Comment: I never had to implement a Root algorhithm. But is there a problem with just using `Math.Pow((double)nrToRoot, 1f / nthRoot)`?

Comment: Well yes since that is what I am supposed to write myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public double RootMethod(double rootExponent, double number)
{

    double guess = 1;
    double accuracyFactor = 0.0001;
    double difference = 1;
    double result = 1;
    double rootExponentMinusOne = rootExponent - 1;

    while (difference > accuracyFactor)
    {
        result = ((guess * rootExponentMinusOne) + (number / (Math.Pow(guess, rootExponentMinusOne)))) / rootExponent;

        difference = result - guess;

        if (difference < 0)
        {
            difference *= -1;
        }


        guess = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hope this is good enough for you. But be aware that this can still produce wrong results, if the accuracy Factor isnt high enough.

Comment: I kinda just copy pasted this, since i had it lying around for my own calculator.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it.